# Push segue with Storyboards

Tags: ios, interface-builder, segue, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I'm using storyboards for my universal (iPhone/iPad) app. I'm using the default master/detail split view.

On split view, everything is working fine, when I select an item in the master view, it's pushed in the detail view. But on iPhone, when I select an item, the detail view is presented like a modal popover (not sure of the name), and not with a push transition (with a right to the left transition and a back button).

Is there something wrong on my storyboard ? The segue between the master and the detail is a "Show (e.g. Push)" segue.

[image: My storyboard]

EDIT: I noticed that I was not very clear in what I wanted ! So here are some gifs.

Here is how my app is working : http://gph.is/1IcN78K

As you see, the detail view is presented with a popover.

Here is how I want it to work (this is a capture of the previous version of my app, I was not using storyboards and I was using Obj-C) : http://gph.is/1IcNKPE

EDIT 2 : Still in need for help. I tried a lot of things, I made a lot of research, but can't find a solution.

Comment: It's hard to be clear exactly what you want, or how exactly your image relates to the problem description (what represents what?), but to me, that you have a segue connected from the table view (which is already embedded in a nav controller) to another nav controller (rather than that VC below the Table VC) is a little suspicious... I'm not sure I'd do it this way...

Comment: @nhgrif yes, it seemed weird to me also, but that's how the default master/detail project is made ! I will edit my post with some gifs to explain what I want exactly !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create segue from your table view to target view and enter identifier
2. Implement this function:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView:UITableView,
    accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: self)

   }
   ```

Comment: That's not the problem, the segue is working fine. See the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear about the problem but you can try -

1. select the segue .
2. The properties related to segue will be shown at right side in XCode & you can change the way the viewcontroller appears .
3. Select segue (this is what you want) .